# shouldComponentUpdate + deepEqual and arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

**Problem:** `shouldComponentUpdate` retrieves previous state with `this.state`, that doesn't work if you keep reference to array at `UserList`, and update array entity at `UserStore`.

***`PureRenderMixin.js`***

```
const deepEqual = require('deep-equal');

module.exports = function pureRenderMixin(Component) {
    Component.prototype.shouldComponentUpdate = function(nextProps, nextState) {
        return !deepEqual(this.props, nextProps) || !deepEqual(this.state, nextState);
    };
    return Component;
};
```

***`UserList.react.js`***

```
class UserList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        UsersStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    }

    _onChange() {            
        this.setState({userList: UsersStore.getState()});
    }
}

module.exports = PureRenderMixin(UserList);
```

***`UsersStore.js`***

```
......
getState() { return _userList; }

switch(action.type) {
   case ActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_FLAG:
       //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
       //PROBLEM: since UserList.react keep userList reference, there is no way to retrieve previous state inside shouldComponentUpdate
       _userList[action.index].flag = action.flag;
       UsersStore.emitChange();
       break;
}
```

### @taggon solution

thanks to taggon, now I know how to make `shouldComponentUpdate` keep the reference to previous state:

***`UsersStore.js`***

```
......
getState() { return _userList; }

switch(action.type) {
   case ActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_FLAG:
       //SOLUTION: copy an array, so there will be two versions of _userList[action.index]
       _userList =  _.map(_userList, _.clone);

       _userList[action.index].flag = action.flag;
       UsersStore.emitChange();
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the store.
The store would be better to create another array whenever its state is changed.

For example, think the store as an array:

```
var store = [ ];

export default store;
```

You may want to write `add()` function like this:

```
export function add(newItem) {
  store = [ ...store, newItem ];
  // or write this in es5
  store = store.concat([newItem]);

  // trigger change event or dispatch an action here
}
```

Likewise, `remove()` function can be:

```
export remove(index) {
  store = [ ...store.slice(0, index), ...store.slice(index+1) ];

  // trigger change event or dispatch an action here
}
```

In this way, the store dereference the component's state whenever the store is changed. This makes`shouldComponentUpdate()` return `true`.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

if your props are immutable, you can compare the data by reference safely and easily. you can have a look at immutablejs

```
class ProductStore extends ReduceStore {
  getInitialState() {
    return Immutable.OrderedMap({1: new Product('react', 'flux'), 2: new Product('angular', 'mvc')});
  }
  reduce (state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'product/item-selected':
        return state.map((product)=> {
          return product.set('selected', product.id === action.id); 
        });
      case 'product/search':
        let alldata = this.getInitialState();
        return alldata.filter((product)=> {
          return product.name.indexOf(action.value) !== -1;
        });
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
}


export default class ProductDetail extends Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.product !== nextProps.product;
  }

  render() {
    const {product} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="product-detail">
        <div className="product-name">
          {product.name}
        </div>
        <div className="product-type">
          {product.type}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: the problem is how to get a reference to previous state inside `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: the data of your componet should be setted by props, you should have your view-controller aka top component to control the data state, in my example, I have a componet called `App` which control the store, and pass the data to my componet `ProductDetail` via props

Comment: why I should keep my data in props? How do that change the situation? I keep that state in state because that is dynamic. That array is actually a list of users which can be followed/unfollowed, change their statuses and so on. And I should reflect that changes on the fly

Comment: then where is your view-controller? you should have a component called `UserList` to render the list, the view-controller keep the state, and it should pass the userList to component `UserList` via `props`, your UserList can be a pure componet with out state

Comment: And I have it. I just tried to simplify code to describe the problem. Look pls at taggon answer, looks like he solves my problem.

Comment: Ok, I don't think you really understand how flux work.

Comment: @Suan sure, it's must pass lots of time till I get your flux level